# Gradle warnings on Kotlin multiplatform dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, warnings, kotlin-multiplatform

I am building a Kotlin Multiplatform project. In my main  `build.gradle` file, I define the several modules and their dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.21'
}

android { ... }

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

kotlin {
    android()
    jvm { 
        compilations.main.kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        compilations.test.kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
                api project(':core')
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
        }
        jvmMain.dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-jdk8')
        }
        jvmTest.dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
        }
        androidMain.dependencies { ... }
        androidTest.dependencies { ... }
    }
}
```

Although the project builds and works fine, IDEA displays a warning on all these dependencies:

[image: Gradle warnings on Kotlin Multi Platform dependencies]

#### Any idea why these warnings are here, e.g. a problem in the project setup? Is there a way I can make them disappear?

Comment: I have no idea why this error appears but I personally like to write it without the Kotlin. ex: implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")